# Strings holding exact same value still returning false when compared

Tags: apex, data-types, apex-variable

I have 2 string variables. One of them holds data retrieved from custom metadata and another is explicitly declared. Both return exact same data when debugged, but still if I compare them, it returns false.

What can be the possible reason? Also please suggest how I can make them the same, as I have a bigger business logic involving this.

Thank you.

PS_Set__c field is of type Long Text Area.

Data stored in PS_Set__c in custom metadata is exactly in this format:  Test A, Test B, Test C

```
List<Custom_Test__mdt> p = [SELECT PS_Set__c from Custom_Test__mdt];

List<String> split = p[0].PS_Set__c.split(',');

string keyword = 'Test C';

system.debug(split[2]==keyword);                // returning false
system.debug(string.valueof(split[2])==keyword);    // returning false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is space in the string stored in custom metadata. Either remove the space or use trim to remove the space from the string

```
e.g. system.debug(split[2].trim()==keyword);
```

Comment: Thank brother, lifesaver.

Answer (score -2):

for comparing string in Apex, you should always use the String class and its method [e.g. firstString.equals(secondString)]. it will give you a correct comparision result by checking data type as well.

refer this link: [Apex String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_equals)

Comment: eh, -1 from me because this information is incomplete and a bit incorrect. String's `equals()` has effectively the same type checks as `==` does. Matching types doesn't guarantee that you'll get the result _that you think you should be getting_. If this were an issue of types, you would almost certainly be getting an error trying to save the code in the first place. It's also a case-sensitive equality check (unlike `==` which is case-insensitive). It's also longer to type. Unless you're using the string method for the sake of being consistent in your codebase, `==` is probably preferred.